# Is it true that $|Gal(K/F)|$ divide $[K:F]$?

Tags: field-theory

Assume that $K/F$ be a  field extension such that $[K:F]=p$, for some prime $p$.We know that $|Gal(K/F)|\leq [K:F] $. Is it true that $|Gal(K/F)|=1$ or $p$?

Comment: One only usually writes Gal$(K/F)$ when $K/F$ is Galois. Then the order of the Galois group is $|K:F|$.

Comment: $Gal(K/F)$ is the Galois group of the field extension $K/F$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: You don't need a Galois extension to consider the group of $F$-automorphisms of $K$. In particular, my definition of a Galois extension is that $|\text{Gal}(K/F)| = [K:F]$.

Comment: one of the best refrences of Galois Theorey is Morandi's book. "Field and Galois Theory."  Definition 2.1 of Morani' s book:

Comment: Definition 2.1: Let $K$ be a filed extension of $F$. The Galois group $Gal(K/F)$ is the set of all $F$-automorhisms of $K$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't get it, since $E = K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you are working with $Aut_F(K)$. Let $E$ be the fixed field of this group of automorphisms. Then by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory $K/E$ is Galois extension and $[K:E]=|Gal(K/E)|$ .Note that $[K:E]=p$ or $1$. In the latter case $E=K$ and $Aut_F(K)=1$ .In the latter case we have $[E:F]=1$ so $K/F$ becomes a Galois extension and hence $[K:F]=p=|Gal(K/F)|$